# How do I free pVect so that memory can be used again?

Tags: c++, object, vector, magnitude

The code is

```
Vect::~Vect()
/*
PRE:  None
POST: free pVect
*/
{
    cout << "(__||  - DELETE (unlock the memory for): " << (*this) << endl;
    // Put code below ....


}
```

Basically, I need it to correctly free pVect so that my other fuctions can work.

Also there is a .h file with this
double* pVect;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them (like removing totally unrelated tags, like the C language tag).

Comment: We can't possibly help given only the information in the question.

Comment: I'll post another question in 2 hours with all the information

Comment: No don't post the same question again, instead **[edit]** your current question to add information.

Comment: Alright I just edited it :D

Comment: After you add a destructor you may get into a problem of double deletes. You probably want to read about this:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if you'd provided a full but minimally-producable example to start with. Let's try this:

```
class Vect {
public:
    ~ Vect();
private:
    double *pVect = nullptr;
};

Vect::~ Vect() {
    delete [] pVect;
}
```

Make sure you keep `pVect` equal to a `nullptr` unless it contains a valid address. Which means you absolutely should give it a default value like I did.